# Serving .json file to download

Tags: python, django

I am trying to serve a .json file through this function. The problem is that every time I make the request the browser displays the content instead of downloading the file.

I think it could be due to the fact that I am using `.read()` as a parameter for the HttpResponse object constructor. However, if I use only the file object, I get the following exception:

```
TypeError: cannot serialize '_io.BufferedRandom' object
```

Code

```
try:
    invoices = models.Invoice.objects.filter(pk__in=document_ids).order_by(*ordering)
    pcustomers = models.CustomerProxy.objects.all()
    mixed_query = list(invoices) + list(pcustomers)

    file = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix='.json')
    file.write(serializers.serialize('json', mixed_query).encode())
    file.seek(0)

    response = HttpResponse(file.read(), content_type='application/json')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s' % file.name
    response['Content-Length'] = os.path.getsize(file.name)

except Exception:
    raise

return response
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You don't need to go through the whole file generation process to create a downloadable file, you just need to add the Content-Disposition header normally. Does the code below work?

```
...
mixed_query = list(invoices) + list(pcustomers)
json_str = serializers.serialize('json', mixed_query))
response = HttpResponse(json_str, content_type='application/json')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=export.json'
```

Comment: The file is generated and I can see it under `/tmp`. I just can't make it be served as a downloadable file instead of a content.

Comment: You don't need to go through the whole file generation process to create a downloadable file, you just need to add the Content-Disposition header.
How does it work if you simplify the code, remove the whole file creation part as I'm doing in the code above?

Comment: If I do that I have the same result as before, which is the page displayed as json.

Comment: I have tried similar code at home and do get an attachment.
I suspect that your browser may be associated with the JSON file type.
Can you try it (a) with another browser (b) with another content_type (e.g. text/plain or application/x-invoices)

Comment: I had a function encapsulating the request and replacing the header. You were right. After a lot of hours trying to see what was wrong I missed this small detail. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the code that you show, you do not need to write to a temporary file. Why don't you just pass the result of `serialize()` into `HttpResponse()`?

```
response = HttpResponse(serializers.serialize('json', mixed_query), content_type='application/json')
```

You can set the attachment name to whatever you like, something descriptive would seem to be better than the random alphanumeric string generated by `tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()`.

```
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="invoices_and_customers.json"'
```

If you really want to specify the length:

```
response['Content-Length'] = len(response.content)
```

or you could add the [`ConditionalGetMiddleware`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/middleware/#module-django.middleware.http) middleware to your settings and have Django add the `Content-Length` for you.

Comment: Exactly. We are using a function to encapsulate the request and in the end it was replacing the header. I will give the right answer to him since he might be eager to get more points once he's a beginner :p. Thanks!

Comment: Fair enough. Also @raphv answered first.

Answer (score 1):

add this to your Http response

```
HttpResponse(mimetype='application/force-download')
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I am using Python 3.5 and it says there is no mimetype attribute to that constructor. Maybe if you meant `content_type="application/force-download"`, I tried that and it did either.