# Force Download existing JSON file instead of displaying it with Django

Tags: django

My webpage has a functionality that lets users request fairly large json files (3MB+) to be generated. The generation process takes some time and I send them an email with a download link once it is ready.

My problem is that clicking the download URL will open the content of the json file in the browser instead of starting a download dialog.

I have found this question: [Serving .json file to download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37298021/serving-json-file-to-download) but the solution reserialize the json file into the response:

```
mixed_query = list(invoices) + list(pcustomers)
json_str = serializers.serialize('json', mixed_query))
response = HttpResponse(json_str, content_type='application/json')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=export.json'
```

As the JSON file already exists, I do not want to rewrite it entirely within the response. I just want users to download the already generated file.

How can I force the URL to start a download when reached?

I am using `Django 3.1`, with `Python 3.6`

Here is the email template sent to users once the download link is ready:

```
{% extends "emails/email_css.html" %}

{% block mail_content %}
    <p>Hi, {{ username }}</p>

    <p>Your export for {{ export_name }} is ready!</p>
    <p>The file will be available for download for 2 days, or until you request a new export.</p>

    <a class="download_button" type="button" href={{ download_url }}>Download</a>
{% endblock %}
```

Edit:
I also tried this solution [How to download file using anchor tag <a>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21607309/how-to-download-file-using-anchor-tag-a) but the json file still gets shown in the browser instead of being downloaded.

Comment: Can you show the HTML for this download? For example, a button?

Comment: @DeanElliott I added the email template to the question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to download file using anchor tag <a>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21607309/how-to-download-file-using-anchor-tag-a)

Comment: I saw this question too, but when I try it, it still opens the file directly in the browser instead of downloading it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually found how to do it, by returning a [FileResponse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/request-response/#fileresponse-objects) with `as_attachment=True`.

```
from django.http import FileResponse

def download_export(request):
    response = FileResponse(open("path/to/file.json", 'rb'), as_attachment=True,
                            filename="file_name.json")
    return response
```

Comment: Does it work on mobile? I'm having a similar issue (with Rails, but the same headers). It works perfectly fine on desktop, but if I try it with my phone (iOS, Firefox) it will display the content of the JSON.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding the `download` property to the `<a>` tag. You can optionally specify a download filename or not.

Without filename:

```
<a class="download_button" type="button" href={{ download_url }} download>Download</a>
```

With filename:

```
<a class="download_button" type="button" href={{ download_url }} download="someJsonFile.json">Download</a>
```

See docs [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp) for the `download` property. Also the related StackOverflow post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21607309/how-to-download-file-using-anchor-tag-a).

Comment: Unfortunately this still opens the json directly inside the browser instead of downloading it (both with and without the filename)